# Why are the numbers on keyboard numpads are not arranged like ATM or phone keypads?

Tags: keyboard, telephony, keypad

Why did designers not arrange the numbers on numpads like ATM or phone keypads?

I mean, `7 8 9 - 4 5 6 - 1 2 3 - 0` vs. `1 2 3 - 4 5 6 - 7 8 9 - 0`.

Does human brain work the reverse way when working with computer keyboard?

**Computer keyboard numpad:**

[image: comp]

**ATM keypad:**

[image: atm]

**Phone keypad:**

[image: tel]

Comment: There are only theories. No specific reason. See: [Keyboard trivia](http://www.vcalc.net/Keyboard.htm) and [Why is the keypad arrangement different for a telephone and a calculator?](http://www.howstuffworks.com/question641.htm)

Comment: The brain doesn't work in reverse, but you do learn to use both separately and switch contexts. See also http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16666/why-do-numpads-on-keyboards-and-phones-have-reversed-layouts

Comment: See also https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/15611/1932 .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second [link](http://www.howstuffworks.com/question641.htm) that slhck posted hits it right on the head.  The keyboard number pad has the layout it does because that's the same way a calculator is laid-out.  The idea was that accountants and others who frequently-used calculators would find it easier to use the number pad, as opposed to the numbers off of the top row.

As a developer, I always hit numbers off of the top-row of the keyboard.  On the other hand, I have two friends who are CPAs and they frequently use the number pad...and they are incredibly fast when they do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try labeling a calculator keypad with the letters A-Z in the same way they're arranged on a telephone keypad (taken from the old dial telephones) and typing something like 1-800-GET-SPAM. You'll find that the alphabet is reversed in 3-letter chunks. That's what the old Bell Labs test was about - speed of typing alphabetic "phone numbers" on different key layouts. If they had used a calculator format, all the companies with mnemonic phone numbers would have been up in arms.

Comment: how stupid of Bell Labs